# Can we only define anonymous function inside constructor of class?

Tags: php

```
<?php 
class Foo
{
    public $bar;
    public $var;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->bar = function() {
            return 42;
        };
    }

    public function test(){
        $this->var = function() {
            return 44;
        };
    }
}

$obj = new Foo();
echo ($obj->bar)(), "<br/>";
var_dump($obj->test());

?>
```

Output: 42
        NULL

Where i am doing wrong I want to get var value inside test function which 44.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: `$obj->test()` just assgins a function to a variable, it doesn't execute this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this method call `$obj->test()`, you're just assigning a function to the instance variable `$var`. And that's why when you do `var_dump($obj->test());`, it shows `NULL` because the method doesn't return anything.

Instead what you can do is, return `$this` from `test()` method and use the current instance to call that anonymous function, like this:

```
class Foo{
    public $bar;
    public $var;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->bar = function() {
            return 42;
        };
    }

    public function test(){
        $this->var = function() {
            return 44;
        };
        return $this;
    }
}

$obj = new Foo();
echo ($obj->bar)(), "<br/>";
echo ($obj->test()->var)();
```

Here's [**the demo**](https://eval.in/826027).